# How to change the Time of the datepicker?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

Currently i developing a WPF application. My application allow user to select any date from the datepicker and data from the selected date will show up. However, user is not allow to select any specific time from the datepicker. The output from the datepicker will be something like `02-dec-2012 12:00:00 AM`. The time from the datepicker will always be 12:00am. So, how can i allow user to alter the time?
I found some resource from [DateTimePicker](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker&referringTitle=Home), but i looking for another solution. Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WPF DatePicker doesn't support time selection or display. It only supports Date picking.

A simple workaround is to use several TextBox controls and bind their Text property to a DateTime data source to allow the user to see and change the time.

For more information about DataBinding, please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx.

If you want to add time picking feature to DatePicker, you will need to introduce custom control.

For more information about Custom Control, please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/44c2d5b9-3b8a-4b3d-8e74-8c9a5612442d/)

you can also take a look at the following example for how to do this: [Example Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126762/A-couple-of-tricks-when-using-the-standard-WPF-NET)